# Is it possible for Rust to iterate over all the types in a module?

Tags: rust, higher-kinded-types, static-reflection

I have trait like this to describe the structure of a type, if I know the type at compile-time, of course I can inspect all the **associate constants, associate types, and static member functions** of it. But the point is, there're hundreds(or even more countless) of types defined in a module, which all satisfy this `TypeModule` trait, but I only got a `TypeID` value from run-time, how can I identify which is the right type I want and inspect all its **associate constants, associate types, and static member functions**?

```
pub trait Value: std::fmt::Debug {
    const SERIALIZED_SIZE_HINT: usize; //此NBT数据类型序列化的预估大小
    fn deserialize_from(src: &[u8]) -> DynamicValue;//必须正确实现，返回的type_id必须正确，不允许失败，无论src为何都必须返回一个正确的DynamicValue
    fn serialize_into(dynamic_value: &DynamicValue) -> Vec<u8>;//不允许失败，因为内存中的DynamicValue的数据一定处于正确的状态
}
///每个ID写一个类型，实现这个Trait，静态分发用
pub trait TypeModule {
    const TYPE_ID: TypeID<'static>;
    const TAG_LIST: &'static [Tag];
    type BlockValue: Value;
    type EntityValue: Value;
    type ItemValue: Value;
    fn get_type_info() -> TypeInfo {
        let block = if !is_same_type::<Self::BlockValue, ()>() {Some(SerializeDeserializeFunctions{
            deserialize_from: Self::BlockValue::deserialize_from,
            serialize_into: Self::BlockValue::serialize_into,
            serialize_size_hint: Self::BlockValue::SERIALIZED_SIZE_HINT,
        })} else {None};
        let entity = if !is_same_type::<Self::EntityValue, ()>() {Some(SerializeDeserializeFunctions{
            deserialize_from: Self::EntityValue::deserialize_from,
            serialize_into: Self::EntityValue::serialize_into,
            serialize_size_hint: Self::EntityValue::SERIALIZED_SIZE_HINT,
        })} else {None};
        let item = if !is_same_type::<Self::ItemValue, ()>() {Some(SerializeDeserializeFunctions{
            deserialize_from: Self::ItemValue::deserialize_from,
            serialize_into: Self::ItemValue::serialize_into,
            serialize_size_hint: Self::ItemValue::SERIALIZED_SIZE_HINT,
        })} else {None};
        TypeInfo {
            type_id: Self::TYPE_ID,
            tags: Self::TAG_LIST,
            block_functions: block,
            entity_functions: entity,
            item_functions: item,
        }
    }
}
```

Is that possible to write code iterating all the types in a module, so I can compare their associate TYPE_ID with the run-time given value and get the correct **TAG_LIST,SERIALIZED_SIZE_HINT and all the member function pointers**?

The closest effort I made is adding an function to TypeModule to turn a type into a TypeInfo value:

```
///Helper Function
struct SameType<T1, T2> {}
impl<T1, T2> SameType<T1, T2> {
    const VALUE :bool = false;
}
impl<T> SameType<T, T> {
    const VALUE :bool = true;
}
fn is_same_type<T1, T2>() -> bool {SameType::<T1, T2>::VALUE}

#[derive(PartialEq,Eq,Copy,Clone)]
pub enum Tag {

}

pub struct SerializeDeserializeFunctions {
    deserialize_from: fn(&[u8]) -> DynamicValue,
    serialize_into: fn(&DynamicValue) -> Vec<u8>,
    serialize_size_hint: usize,
}

///write an instance of this type for every id, for dynamic dispatching
pub struct TypeInfo {
    type_id: TypeID<'static>,
    tags: &'static [Tag],
    block_functions: Option<SerializeDeserializeFunctions>,
    entity_functions: Option<SerializeDeserializeFunctions>,
    item_functions: Option<SerializeDeserializeFunctions>,
}
```

I can turn a pre-known type into `TypeInfo` but I don't know how check for hundreds of types of a module.

Comment: @sbstnzmr No, RTTI is not what I want(I just implement a much better TypeInfo in the question, which inspects everything of a TypeModule type). I want to iterate over all the types in a module. Please read my question before you try to answer.

Comment: I guess it might be possible if Rust implement vardic template? But Rust just doesn't support that yet